# Which scripture is this shloka from? (hariṇā cāśava de yetī)

Tags: scripture, puranas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify which scripture this sloka is from. I came across this an audio lecture:

> hariṇā cāśava de yetī

हरिणा चाशव दे येती

```
हरिणा (hariṇā): By Lord Hari
च (cā): And
आशव (āśava): Blessings, divine favor
देयेति (deyeti): Is given or should be given
```

any suggestions are appreciated